# Bootstrap 4 Navigation Bar Toggle Not Working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Here is my code from Bootstrap documentation for a responsive nav bar. However, when I make the browser window (in Chrome/Safari) to mobile size, the toggle dropdown does not seem to work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-text">
    Navbar text with an inline element
    </span>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS & JS File working fine

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-text">
    Navbar text with an inline element
    </span>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y5n0xot1/

Answer (score 0):

Adding jquery in Angular Project is not recommended because the way angular manipulates the DOM to render page is different than how jquery does.

So Here is the Best fix for this issue:

**Step 1 :** Install ngx-bootstrap in your angular project after adding bootstrap 4

> npm install ngx-bootstrap --save

**Step 2 :** In app.module.ts : import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';

inject CollapseModule as root such that its available in all components and modules.

> imports: [
>       ...,
>       CollapseModule.forRoot()   ]

**Step 3 :** Add collapse directive on div to toggle on click *[ Extra : You can enable animation via isAnimated input option ]*

```
 <button (click)="isNavbarCollapsed = !isNavbarCollapsed" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isNavbarCollapsed" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div [collapse]="isNavbarCollapsed"  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive" [isAnimated]="true">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Step 4 :** in components.ts initialise **"isNavbarCollapsed"**

```
isNavbarCollapsed = true;
```